# How do I know if a world is Hard or not?

Tags: terraria

Is it possible to just tell from the World Tree?

I've got Hallowed Seeds from one world, and I've planted some in the worlds I want to check, so I dunno if the Hallow is from me, or from the death of the Wall of Flesh.

I know there's some NPCs that are clear signifiers, but I want to figure it out at the earliest possible time.

Answer (score 7):

As per the [Trivia section on World creation](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/World#Trivia) (emphasis mine):

> The leaves of the tree icon when selecting a world will change depending on the status of the world. The left half will always represent the world's naturally spawned evil biome, while the right will be a pure Forest tree. In some secret world seeds, both evil biomes will be native to the world, resulting in a tree that is both Corrupt and Crimson with no pure representation. **In Hardmode, the bottom right quarter and half of the left branch will turn yellow, representing The Hallow.**

Like you said, there are many other things that change upon defeating the Wall of Flesh and unleashing hardmode in a particular world, as listed on the [Hardmode](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Hardmode) page. Personally, I believe the simplest method is to try and **destroy Hellstone using Dynamite or Bombs**. This is only possible in Hardmode, and the underworld is one of the safest areas in early Hardmode.

Ignoring searching for NPCs which is somewhat random, one can also look for Chlorophyte in the Jungle (spawns even before you break Altars) or fish up some Crates.

Comment: FYI, my Hallowed Seeds are from one world used in another. added that to clarify in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You're highly likely on hardmode, according to [fandom](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Hallowed_Seeds)'s hallowed seed's description:

> Hallowed Seeds are Hardmode seeds

And also, [archive of fandom](https://terraria-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Hallowed_Seeds) says:

> They can be purchased from the Dryad **after defeating the Wall of Flesh**.

Emphasis mine.

Though, you can still bring hallowed seeds from other world, so I can't know for sure. But if you don't have any other worlds, then you're highly likely on the hardmode (you can still bring them from multiplayer world, so...). Same thing can be said to [Pwnhammer](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Pwnhammer), it'll be dropped from Wall of Flesh by 100% drop rate, so if you have it then you're most likely on hardmode, but well, you can bring it from any other world.

Apart from that...

> I know there's some NPCs that are clear signifiers, but I want to figure it out at the earliest possible time.

Well, I think that's the fastest and most reliable way to know if your world is on hardmode: If [Merchant](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Merchant) is around you and he sells Disco Ball/Gold Dust, then you're on hardmode, since he only sells that item after beating Wall of Flesh.

Comment: FYI, my Hallowed Seeds are from one world used in another. added that to clarify in the question.